# google script : IO error when deserializing continuation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I wrote a script that adds a function in a Google spreadsheet that was working well. From today, I get an error:

> IO error when deserializing continuation.

This appears after a call to `Ui.alert` or `Ui.prompt`. I tried to add sleep after the calls, but it doesn’t work. This is a sample of code:

```
ui.alert( "ERROR. !");
Utilities.sleep(1000);
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem using a script to merge mail from spreadshhet.

I saw a post from year 2014 that explains this  is a error server at Google end and ot in any coe of any script.

Next day the problem was solved by itself. It's a problem from Google...

Comment: Can you please provide the link you found in 2014 and a quote of the part from the link that is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this error for the first time today. I got the script working again by running another function that worked, when I went back and executed the problematic function it was then working again.

In another case, a user reported they were getting this error. Closing and re-opening the spreadsheet helped the affected user.

Probably a Google issue and not something directly related to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Could system latency (PC + Internet) be the cause? This would explain apparent randomness, and be fixable on Google's end by increasing the timeout associated with the Browser.msgbox I/O process.